# Documentation for user-defined functions; undocumented documentation feature?

Tags: front-end, bugs, documentation, undocumented

I stumbled on some strange behaviour when trying out the new function template and documentation features, now purportedly working in v 9.0.1.  I defined a function `f` and `f::usage="f[x] does something to x"`.  Typing `f` and then `Cmd+Shift+K` pulls up a tab and, as with built-in functions, there is an area marked `Documentation` underneath the completion section. Clicking on that (I always wanted an easy way to extend the built-in documentation; the approach described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6574710/integrating-notebooks-to-mathematicas-documentation-center) is rather too much of a meal for me) I was given what looks like a notebook view on a directory (the directory shown is the working directory for my notebook):
[image: Opening a directory]

Feeling foolhardy, I thought I'd try to save it (well, I do have a recent bootable backup, TM snapshots and my files are under git/Dropbox control):
[image: Undocumented feature(?) -> error message]

I was relieved to find that the file could not be written, as it seems to correspond to a directory, which I don't think you can open via the front end and I hope can't be directly written in that way either?  It can be "saved as", default being `Consultancy.txt`

So, to my question: bug or (undocumented?) feature?  Can I use this to do something useful for documentation of my own functions?

Comment: This happens to me occassionally as well... just close the windows and reopen the documentation center. It's possibly some obscure FE bug

Comment: Doesn't seem to happen with the Windows FE. If I had to guess, I'd say it indeed looks like some sort of bug.

Comment: Have you reported this to WRI?

Comment: @Kuba no, it was some way down my stack of bugs to report at the time and the stack got deeper in the meantime :-)  Also, as rm -rf seems to have misunderstood the behaviour I'm reporting I thought it might be difficult to give clear enough instructions for the problem to be reproduced.

Comment: @rm-rf I'm not sure if you've understood me here, because this wasn't something that just happened to me, I had to work at it.  To clarify: the little box that comes up with the documentation of a built-in function does _not_ appear automatically, but Cmd+Shift+K brings it up anyway, and that's when this strange behaviour occurs if you click on "Documentation".  Same issue if I start with a fresh MMA.

Comment: @fairflow I think I've understood you perfectly, and as I said before, this occurs to me as well and is fixed by simply closing and reopening the doc center. I have not, however, tried to reproduce this at will and never bothered because the "fix" was quite simple. Since no one has been able to do anything here for 4+ months, perhaps writing to support@wolfram.com might give you better chances :)